# inner container not repeating-y for stick footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I wanted a sticky footer to I followed this guide: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

I have in out wrap(container) and an inner wrap(container2) used for background images.

I was able to get the footer to stick to the bottom but the background image in container2 is not repeating vertically all the way down.

Need some assistance please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to repeat the background, ensure you have the css..

```
background:url('path/to/image.png') repeat-y 0 0;
```

Edit: ugly hack (working) -

```
$('#container2').css('min-height',document.height - 30);
```

Edit: additional solution -

apply the background image to the body

Comment: Fix `backround` typo. Also, are you going for some kind of record on the most number of answers posted in a single day?

Comment: @thirtydot what's the current record?

Comment: @Orbit: No idea, you might consider asking on Meta. At any rate, I'm sure you're the winner.

Comment: Ok, so after some testing, I used the above directive with your background image, and I got a permission denied trying to set it with jQuery in my console. Using some random picture of cats, it worked.

Comment: @Orbit, I don't quite follow. If I add more content, it works fine but for pages that are a little short on content, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dru - still looking at it, 1 minute. I see the problem now.

Comment: Ugly jQuery hack posted above, still looking though

Comment: @Orbit, thanks. That works but resizing the window causes it to scroll.

Comment: @Dru - not sure that is preventable, happens also w/ old configuration, albeit later

Comment: @Orbit, what I mean was that it scrolls even with no content which shouldn't happen and doesn't happen currently.

Comment: @Dru - Ok, I see what you are saying. can you just apply the background to the body?

Comment: @Orbit, 1 minute, let me try that now

Comment: @Dru Awesome, you are going to have to remove the background from the elements over the body to get it to show, but I got my kittens to show up (eventually)

Comment: @Orbit, that seems to have worked and window resizes don't seem to effect it. Can't believe I didn't think of that earlier. Thanks for all your help buddy!!!

Comment: @Dru, no problem, can't believe I didn't think of it earlier myself :)